# How to know the index of page table to update PTE when the physical page is evicted from the memory?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

If OS found the page frame to be evicted,

it has to look up page table (maybe via special register) and invalidate page table entry.

The problem is, while we can index page table entry (in the page table) from the virtual address,

**we cannot index page table entry (in the page table) from the physical address.**

How does OS find the index of page table to be updated when the page is evicted?

In addition, when the page is evicted to secondary storage, is the page always evicted to the same

location of the secondary storage? (or just get the free space to be evicted at the time of eviction?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has ramifications in a lot of OS theory. To understand better, you can look at x86 Linux and how this OS on this architecture does things.

Here's a short version for reference. Each swap area has a swap_info_struct. Each swap_info_struct is stored in a statically defined list called swap_info which has 32 entries.

```
 64 struct swap_info_struct {
 65     unsigned int flags;
 66     kdev_t swap_device;
 67     spinlock_t sdev_lock;
 68     struct dentry * swap_file;
 69     struct vfsmount *swap_vfsmnt;
 70     unsigned short * swap_map;
 71     unsigned int lowest_bit;
 72     unsigned int highest_bit;
 73     unsigned int cluster_next;
 74     unsigned int cluster_nr;
 75     int prio;
 76     int pages;
 77     unsigned long max;
 78     int next;
 79 };
```

Each swap area is divided in page sized slots. Meaning 4096 bytes on x86. The first slot is used to store info on the swap area (the header). The rest of the slots are actual pages swapped out. Swap areas can be files or a partition on disk.

When a page is evicted, the page table entry corresponding to the page is changed to a swp_entry_t struct. This struct holds a value which has several meanings. Bit 0 is reserved for the page present flag which is set to 0 so that a page fault occurs when a program tries to read that data. Bits 1-6 are for the index in the swap_info array (the actual swap area which holds the evicted page). Bits 8-31 are the offset in the swap area where the page lies. It has 24 bits which limits the swap area size to 64GB (with pages of 4KB).

```
 16 typedef struct {
 17     unsigned long val;
 18 } swp_entry_t;
```

For more info read the following https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html

Each process has a task_struct which holds that process information. The task_struct holds a member named mm which is itself a struct holding a member named pgd. pgd is a pointer to the first level of page table for that process. By dereferencing pgd, we can reach the data belonging to the different page tables. For example, if you type `*pgd` you get the actual first entry of the first level of page table. This first entry is the address of the bottom of the next level page table. So you basically have a pointer to the next level page table. It means that, if you write `**pgd`, you get the value of the next level page table. You get the point that by using pgd we can reach all page tables.

When a page fault occurs, it can mean a few things and an error code is pushed on the stack so that the OS can determine what caused the page fault. If the page had the present bit not set it probably means the page was evicted to secondary storage. Then IP (the program counter) will be pushed on the stack to handle the page fault. Linux finds the offending address by looking onto the stack of the process. Once it finds the offending address, it accesses the actual page tables using the pgd pointer and then swaps in the page which was evicted.

When a page is swapped out, it will be stored to a swap area based on a priority scheme which I'm not really aware of. When a page is swapped in, it will be allocated the memory that the new evicted page had. Because if pages are evicted it means memory is full so that to swap in a page, you must swap out another page. The swapped in page takes the place of the swapped out page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the answer does not include what I want to know. When the page is evicted, we can surely reference the **page table**. However, after we get the address of page table, **how to index the page table entry** to evict the page from the physical address? We need to access the page table entry in the page table to turn of the valid bit.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand your question. I see you are missing the big picture here but it seems I cannot help.

Comment: Maybe try to reformulate your question and compare some assumptions you make to the answer I provided.

Comment: To summarize my question, when the os wants to swap out physical frame A, how does os find corresponding page table (i think we need mapping from A to process id list). In addition, if we find the page table, we need to do operation like pgtable[i].valid = false. Here how does OS know **i**?

Comment: The page table entry is in the virtual address.

Comment: The virtual address contains offsets in the page tables.

Comment: But we do not have physical to virtual adress mapping

Comment: No, to determine what virtual address references a physical address from only the physical address is impossible I think. You cannot do reverse mapping.

Comment: I don't see a situation where that would be useful.